# React: setting state for one variable is also setting a different state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Sorry if the question is weirdly worded.

So these are the steps I have accomplished:

1. fetch an array of news articles from NewsAPI
2. set state and display on page
3. when the favorite icon is clicked, set an array in favorite state
4. on the favorites component, display articles that were favorited.

for #5, I am trying to give the user the ability to remove a favorite by clicking on the favorite icon located on each favorited article displayed (this is on the page /favorites using a grid to display the articles favorited). My first problem is that when I click on the icon, the article is removed from favorites and the page is re-rendered and the article no longer displays because it is being mapped using favorites. I want the user to be able to re-favorite if they change their mind before leaving /favorites.

My solution to this is to use the temporary favoritesToDisplay state to populate on the favorites component. This way, the favorites state wont change and the page wont re-render.

**To my surprise setting state to favorites also changes favoritesToDisplay. Does anyone know why this is happening? this is occurring when addOrRemoveFavorite is called.**

```
const [favorites, setToFavorites] = useState([])

const Favorites = () =>{
    const [favoritesToDisplay, setFavoritesToDisplay] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      document.body.classList.add('show-overflow')
      setFavoritesToDisplay(favorites)
    }, [])

    const addOrRemoveFavorite = (i) =>{
      setToFavorites(favorites.filter(favorite => favorite !== favoritesToDisplay[i]))
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <h1 id="favorites-page-header">Favorites</h1>
        {favoritesToDisplay[0] && <div id="news-cards-container">

          {favoritesToDisplay.map((card, index) => (<section className="news-card" key={card.url} id={index}>
            <div id="card-top-container" style={backgroundSettings(card.urlToImage, "center/cover no-repeat ")}>
              <div id="bookmark-icon-container">
                <i id="card-favorite" className="material-icons" onClick={() => addOrRemoveFavorite(index)}>favorite</i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="card-info-nav">
                <div id="card-info-container">
                  <h2 id="card-title">{card.title}</h2>
                  <div id="card-source-author-container">
                    <h3 id="card-source-and-author">{card.source.name} - {card.author}</h3>
                    <h4 id="card-date">{formatDate(card.publishedAt)}</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>                
                  <div id="card-button-container">
                    <a href={card.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
                      <i className="material-icons">import_contacts</i>
                      <span>Read More</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </section>))}

        </div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Why is your hook outside of the function?

Comment: its from another component. I just wanted to show it without the entire component that it is from. The articles that were favorited are in that state when the Favorites component is first rendered..